# Exception on device only: This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key bookingDateLabel

Tags: iphone, ios7, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xcode-storyboard

Really puzzled by this exception message while building a Xamarin iOS Universal storyboard app the last few days. I receive this exception when debugging on device while building my custom `UITableViewCell` (`BookingItemCellController` which is specified as class on the UITableViewCell in xcode storyboard) followed by the application & debugger crashing:

> NSUnknownKeyException Reason: [
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key bookingDateLabel.
>   (MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException)

The line it crashes on is the `var cell..` line within `GetCell`:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
  var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (CellIdentifier, indexPath);
  var item = TableItems[indexPath.Row];
..
```

The most puzzling thing is, my table view loads and items show up and I can flick through them on the simulator, and I only receive this error while debugging on an iPhone 4 with iOS 7.

`bookingDateLabel` does exist in my .designer.cs file created by a valid outlet:

```
[Outlet]
[GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
MonoTouch.UIKit.UILabel bookingDateLabel { get; set; }
```

Again, this works in the simulator, but not on device. How can this be?
Any thoughts gang?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

OMFG..... I've found the answer. Sorry and I don't mean to swear, but I spent about 3 hours on this today, I even made new class files with the same error coming up on a different filename, which really got me.

One of the first suggestions you will read on the net regarding this is trying to clean your solution and rebuilding. I tried that. Apparently clean wasn't good enough. I just went in and deleted both my `bin` and `obj` folders and this solved the issue.

For anyone else tearing their hair out over this. My table view is loading fine now. Argh!!

Comment: it happens to all IOS developers

Comment: We clear derived data when every thing else fails :D

Comment: Thanks this bailed me out.  Made a change to storyboard and could not run application on phone, only simulator.